# why char * works with const only

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #define nline "\n"
    
    int main(){
       //const char *p="hello world";
      // court<<p;

        char *p="hello world";
        cout<<p;
    
    
    }
```

C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User\cses2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User\cses2.cpp:7:10: warning: ISO C++ **forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]**
char *p="hello world";
^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: String literals are made up of `const char`s. They may be stored in non-writeable memory. If you wan't something that you can modify: `char str[] = "hello world";` - the `char[]` is then initialized with the string literal.

Comment: Why should a pointer to a constant literal be non const?

Comment: In c++ it's rarely necessary to use `char`, use `std::string` instead or just use C.

Comment: Side notes: (1) About `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h, (2) About `using namespace std;`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: Questions should include text (you know, a question) in addition to code and error messages.

Answer (score 1):

`"hello world"` is a `const char[12]`. A c-array of 12 constant (!) characters (note that one is for the null terminator).

In early C++ standards it was allowed to get a `char *` to a string literal due to compatibility with C. Though, it was nevertheless forbidden to actually modify the characters of the string literal via the `char *`.

This changed in C++11 and since then string literals have proper const correctness.

If you do want a string that can be modified, then use a `std::string`. Note that the pointer you obtain from the literal is not a string, its just a pointer to a (non-modifiable) c-string. If you want a string rather than a pointer to one, you need to use a string.